# How can I remove a potent smell from leather?

Tags: cleaning, furniture

We just bought two used leather chairs.  They are in great condition, but they have a very distinct (rather unpleasant) smell to them.... Is there any safe way to remove this smell without damaging the leather?

It smells like smoke from cigarettes.

Comment: Would febreze do the job? or will this damage the leather?

Comment: If you have a place where these can stay outside for a few days it helps a ton.  Also I would recommend hitting it with febreeze under the chair and into the padding.  Depending on the type of leather you may or may not be able to spray solvents on it.

Comment: @DMoore We considered this, but should I be worried about insects getting inside those chairs? And would placing them in the garage suffice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cigarette stench is a bad one - good luck, you'll need it. I would have moved on to a different sale, personally.

You could try using saddle soap (buy it at a tack shop) and scrubbing the surface down. Follow the instructions on the can. Might need to repeat 3-4 times.

If there's a fabric bottom, remove, discard, and replace it.

You might also consider replacing the stuffing, if its permeated deeply.